# Revoking permissions for Azure AD applications

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I have an issue similar [to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44901065/azure-app-registration-remove-permissions). After revoking the following permissions from my app (Sign in and read user profile & Read all groups), and reassigning completly different permissions (Read user mail + waiting 20 mins for the new permissions to take effect), my app is still able to query/read the domain's group. I have also tried revoking all permissions => the resulting requiredResourceAccess array in the Manifest file for the application is empty; waited 20 mins for the changes to take effect. => result my application is still able to query the domain's group.
Any explanation is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As that case's answer said, after change the permissions in Application registrations, you need to click the **Grant Permissions** button.

Go to Azure portal> Azure Active Directory> Application registrations > Select your application > Required permissions > Choose the API > Revoke the permissions > Save > Grant permissions

[image]

[image]

You can go to Enterprise applications to check if it has revoked.

Enterprise Applications > Select your applications > Permissions

If you want to revoke all permissions of the Application, you can just delete it in Enterprise applications.